# Subtracting Several Products Quantities And Array.Splice Not A Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The problem is on the subtractQuantity function. When i add two products for example, i clicked the subtract quantity button of the first product, the second product also subtracts its quantity. Its supposed to be the first product that subtracts the quantity since i clicked the subtract quantity button of the first product. Second problem is when the quantity is 0, it should automatically remove the product but the Error says that array.splice is not a function. PS: I AM USING ECMASCRIPT 6 so PLEASE FREE TO GUIDE ME IF I'M NOT USING ECMASCRIPT 6 OR WHAT TO IMPROVE IN MY CODE

```js
const cart = {};

function AddtoCart(productid, description, quantity, price) {
  if (cart[productid]) {
    cart[productid].qty += quantity;
  } else {
    cart[productid] = {
      id: productid,
      desc: description,
      qty: quantity,
      price: price
    };
  }
  calculateGrandTotal();
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = GrandTotal;
  console.log(GrandTotal);
  viewCart();
  
  }
  function subtractQuantity(productid){
      if(cart[productid].qty > 0){
        cart[productid].qty--;
      }
      if (cart[productid].qty == 0) {
         delete cart[productid]//Remove from cartreturn false;
      }
    viewCart();
  }

function calculateGrandTotal(){
    GrandTotal = 0;
    for(let productid in cart){
        if(cart.hasOwnProperty(productid)){
            GrandTotal += parseFloat(cart[productid].price) * parseInt(cart[productid].qty);
        }
    }
}
function viewCart() {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('cartsBody');
  tbody.innerHTML = '';
  Object.values(cart).forEach(content => {
    tbody.innerHTML += `<td>${ content.id }</td>
                      <td>${ content.desc }</td>
                      <td>${ content.qty }</td>
                      <td>${ content.price }</td>
                      <td>${ content.qty * content.price }</td>
                      <td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(${content.id})'>subtract Quantity</button></td>`;
  }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Laptop" onclick="AddtoCart('132','Macbook Pro', 1, 79000,0)" />
<input type="button" value="Phone" onclick="AddtoCart('456','Iphone 5S', 1, 18000,0)" />
<input type="button" value="Camera" onclick="AddtoCart('789','Nikon 3D00', 1, 25000,0)" />

<table border="1" id="cartsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="cartsBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
<h4>Total:</h4>
<p id="total"></p>
```

Comment: i think because cart is an object and splice is for arrays

Comment: @AshtonMorgan. Yes that's the problem. Can you help me?

Comment: That is correct what Ashton said. You cannot splice object properties. Use delete instead or create array for the cart.

Comment: @Janne. Can you help me do that?

Comment: Instead of splice try delete cart[produductid]. This removes object property.

Comment: @Janne. Grand total not updating when click subtract quantity button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**working solution**

```js
const cart = {};

function AddtoCart(productid, description, quantity, price) {
  if (cart[productid]) {
    cart[productid].qty += quantity;
  } else {
    cart[productid] = {
      id: productid,
      desc: description,
      qty: quantity,
      price: price
    };
  }
  
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = calculateGrandTotal();
  console.log(GrandTotal);
  viewCart();
  
  }
  function subtractQuantity(productid){
      if(cart[productid].qty > 0){
        cart[productid].qty--;
      }
      if (cart[productid].qty == 0) {
         delete cart[productid]//Remove from cartreturn false;
      }
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = calculateGrandTotal();
    viewCart();
  }

function calculateGrandTotal(){
    GrandTotal = 0;
    for(let productid in cart){
        if(cart.hasOwnProperty(productid)){
            GrandTotal += Number.parseFloat(cart[productid].price) * Number.parseInt(cart[productid].qty);
        }
    }
    return GrandTotal;
}
function viewCart() {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('cartsBody');
  tbody.innerHTML = '';
  Object.values(cart).forEach(content => {
    tbody.innerHTML += `<td>${ content.id }</td>
                      <td>${ content.desc }</td>
                      <td>${ content.qty }</td>
                      <td>${ content.price }</td>
                      <td>${ content.qty * content.price }</td>
                      <td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(${content.id})'>subtract Quantity</button></td>`;
  }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Laptop" onclick="AddtoCart('132','Macbook Pro', 1, 79000,0)" />
<input type="button" value="Phone" onclick="AddtoCart('456','Iphone 5S', 1, 18000,0)" />
<input type="button" value="Camera" onclick="AddtoCart('789','Nikon 3D00', 1, 25000,0)" />

<table border="1" id="cartsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="cartsBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
<h4>Total:</h4>
<p id="total"></p>
```

Comment: Grand total below not updating when clicked subtract quantity. Please check edited snippet

Comment: @Joseph: and now! satisfied? :D

Comment: @Joseph: why would I do that? only questions frequently asked should be upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
cart.splice()
```

Use :

```
delete cart[productid]
```

Splice is for arrays, the other solution is making cart an array :

```
const cart = []
```

**edit**

For the first problem, instead of iterate trough all the cart properties, send the id of the item you want to decrease the cuantity:

```
onClick='subtractQuantity(' +content.id+')'
```

And on your substract function just decrease or delete:

```
function subtractQuantity(productid){

    if(cart.hasOwnProperty(productid)){
        cart[productid].qty--;
    }
    if (cart[productid].qty == 0) {
            delete cart[productid]//Remove     from cart

}
calculateGrandTotal();
viewCart();
```

}

Comment: Well i had a typo its productid not productId

Comment: Yes its working now but the first problem is not yet resolved. Please check my question above.

Comment: The Grand total not also updating when subtracting quantity

Answer (score 0):

`splice` is a method of the `Array` object. If you want to use it on an *array-like* structure

`Array.prototype.splice.call(cart, productid,1)`

As for removing an entry from the cart, you have to pass `this` (the product you want to decrease its quantity) to the handler `onClick='subtractQuantity(this)'` and the function declaration `function subtractQuantity(this)`

ps: how to apply these *instructions* is up to you. Good luck

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to apply this. Can you help me do the Array.prototype.splice.call(cart, productid,1)?